# What is the preferred syntax for spacing out inline child elements with the MUI5 sx prop?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to build a MUI container with several sub-components to be rendered inline but separated by fixed padding. I can do that like this:

```
<Box sx={{display: 'flex', '& > * + *': {ml: 2}}> 
  <div>Thing 1</div>
  <div>Thing 2</div>
</Box>
```

OK, but a bit messy. What's the preferred MUI/CSS technique for laying out components in-line with fixed spacing (i.e., not in a grid) between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but the cleanest in my opinion is using flex and grid gap (especially since most of my layouts will already be using flex to align horizontally/vertically).

```
<Box sx={{display: 'flex', gap: 2}}> 
  <div>Thing 1</div>
  <div>Thing 2</div>
</Box>
```

Or with a Box, even:

```
<Box display="flex" gap={2}> 
  <div>Thing 1</div>
  <div>Thing 2</div>
</Box>
```

See the mozilla docs for details on this property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap